# Who did/do I met today on the way to work?

Tags: tenses, questions

Lets say you have the sentence

> Today I've met an old coleague on the way to work.

What is the question going to be:

> Who did/do I met today on the way to work?

did or do, and why?

EDIT: Also, in the first sentence, is the `I've` right? Or should it be `I met`?

Comment: The question - Who's asking it: yourself or someone else?

Comment: I am saying the first sentence myself, and asking the question myself again.

Comment: yes, dont worry about it if it makes sense or not, I want to know the right way to say it

Comment: Today I met an old colleague on the way to work. Who did you/I meet today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

> Today I met an old colleague on the way to work.

And, for the question:

> Who did I meet on the way to work today?

It's did and not do because it is in the past tense. You aren't currently meeting the colleague on the way to work. Also, because it is the verb `to do`, the verb `to meet` stays in present tense because `do`, along with `be` and `have`, is a primary auxiliary verb.

Edit: I'm assuming you aren't talking about your escapades in daily life as if they were a story. If you were, it would be `Who do I meet on the way to work today?` because narratives are recounted in the present tense. But since you shouldn't talk about your day in normal conversation like it's part of a story, you should use the past tense.

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

*Answer*: Today, I met an old colleague on the way to work.
*Question*: Who did I (you) meet today on the way to work?

You would say, "I met an old colleague" here, because the meeting *occurred* (*simple past*) today. On the other hand, you would say, "I have met him often on my way to work." (*present perfect*)

*Affirmative* versus *Interrogative* forms:

I meet - do I meet? - It's the auxiliary that changes accordingly and not the main verb.
I met - did I meet? - Auxiliary is in the *past*